# Merge two rows of same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

| sn | ID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 3836.68 |
| 1 |  | 1087.63 |
| 2 | 70 |  |
| 3 | 20 | 2863.56 |

I want something like:

| sn | ID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 3836.68 |
| 1 | 70 | 1087.63 |
| 3 | 20 | 2863.56 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace empty strings by `NaN` (no need if empty values are already `NaN`), then backward fill the rows, and finally drop duplicates on `ID` column:

```py
>>> df.replace('', np.nan).bfill(axis=0).drop_duplicates(['ID'])

   sn    ID   Amount
0   0  10.0  3836.68
1   1  70.0  1087.63
3   3  20.0  2863.56
```